# Rgb not working on MSI motherboard

Tags: motherboard, bios, colors, rgb

Today I booted up my computer and none of the RGB is not working including the strip that is on the motherboard I do not recall doing anything that would cause this problem. The RGB strip out on the motherboard itself does not work and that tells me it's most likely a software problem unless of course, the motherboard itself is the issue.

So I went ahead and reinstalled dragon center thinking this would be an easy fix. I did this twice playing with the RGB settings looking to see if missed anything. When this did not work, I went into my Bios settings (MSI click bios 5) and flicked off the RGB control, and restarted.  I did that again turning it on this time no luck there. I then tried to update my Bios and reset to defaults no luck there as well.

At this point, I can't think of anything else that would fix my problem and I could not find any similar issues on the internet so any help will be appreciated thx!  My motherboard is MSI MPG X570 GAMING EDGE WIFI ATX AM4 Motherboard

Comment: Have you changed anything in the hardware just before the problem appeared?

Comment: I did add a second monitor to my setup the day before the problem appeared. I'm not too experienced in the ways of computer building but maybe the extra power draw could make the computer prioritize the second monitor over the RGB.

Comment: If the second monitor is self-powered, there wouldn't be an additional power draw.

Comment: What model is your computer? If you disconnect the second monitor, does it change anything?

Comment: I just did a quick restart without the monitor plugged in with no luck :(... I'm not sure what you are looking for when you wanted to know the model of my computer it is not prebuilt but the full parts list is here https://pcpartpicker.com/user/_Darksaber_/saved/Fr4YHx

Comment: Are you using the latest [BIOS & drivers](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/support/MPG-X570-GAMING-PLUS)?

Comment: Yes as I said above in the main question I updated my Bios and reset it to defaults. I also updated everything in dragon center if that's what you were meaning in terms of drivers.

Comment: By "drivers" I meant the software you see if you click on "Driver" in my above link. If that doesn't help, the problem might be hardware, where I can't help.